# Some $_SERVER parameters missing when accessing PHP script via Cron

Tags: apache-2.2, php, command-line-interface, cron

I have a script that I need to run with PHP via cron. The original author of the script made a lot of user of certain `$_SERVER` parameters (like `REQUEST_URI`).

But it appears that certain variables don't exist when running PHP via command line or via CRON. For example, there is no request uri, so it makes sense that the `REQUEST_URI` parameter wouldn't be available.

Is there any way around this other than to completely rewrite the script in order to avoid using special `$_SERVER` parameters that aren't universally available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't really know the script I would recommend `wget` in your CRON to trigger the script through your webserver as the browser would do.

Dig into `wget http://localhost/yourScript.php` (-O and -o might be interesting or not for still receiving error messages&co) When you need "more", like a login using cookies you might check `curl`

When going to use hack´n´slay as @pQd mentioned and you *can not* edit the 3rdParty script you should take a look at "auto_prepend_file" in your cli.php.ini and consider starting the job using `php -c`

Comment: That's a good idea but we typically keep cron scripts outside of the web root so that it's not accessible to everyone out there.

Comment: When you bind the virtualHost in your apache to 127.0.0.1 its fine ;-)

Comment: `<location /cronjobs>order deny,allow\n deny from all\n allow from 127.0.0.1</location>` or you could even start another instance of apache to split it totally... sorry but this should really be the last problem ;-)

Comment: Yeah normally a lot of apache config is feasible but we are working with a host that doesn't give us any control over it :-(

Comment: Then you still can put that access rule into a .htaccess file (and yes that *can fail*, but your ssh could get bruteforced too)

Comment: I guess this is a good approach as long as the script is protected.

Answer (score 0):

by trial-and-error [analyzing errors printed by the script] or source analysis try figuring out which parameters are expected and at the beginning of the script add: $_SERVER['someName'] = '';$_SERVER['otherName'] = '';

it's very much script dependent - what if it expects some actual values there? what if for instance referrer is checked?

Answer (score 0):

Because apparently serverfault wants to encourage new users to write answers instead of just making simple comments, I'll +1 Tabakhase's answer and add my incremental improvement here.

If you don't want to expose your script to the web, even with the .htaccess protection, you can write a short bash script to achieve your goal.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c16)
cp $script /var/www/host/$file.php
wget --output-document=output.txt http://server/path/to/$file.php
rm /var/www/host/$file.php
```

You'll of course need to fiddle with permissions to make sure whoever is running the cron job can write files to your /var/www, which has its own implications.

Of course you can generate $file using any method you prefer, and can manage the output / headers / etc (even cookies!) by editing the options passed to wget.